# Cauchy principal value for solving the integral of complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, cauchy-principal-value

I need to solve the following integral (if it is possible):

$$\int_0^{\infty}dx\,f(x) \left\{ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{t}e^{i(x-x_0) \tau}d\, \tau \right \}$$

I found an expression in an article which states that the following holds:

$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{t}e^{i(x-x_0) \tau}d\, \tau  = \pi\delta(x-x_0) + \frac{P}{i(x-x_0)}$$

Where $P$ denotes the Cauchy principal value. But I haven't been able to fully understand how to calculate this principal value, and it is also pretty unclear to me where this term originates.

Comment: Is the upper bound on the integral supposed to be $t$?

Comment: Yes sorry, there I made the change

Comment: Still needs to be changed in the first occurrence...

Comment: Anybody? Now it's corrected.